# TWS EXIT status meaning

Tags: tivoli

I was going through the tws logs and found that it gives exit status as 0, 1 and so on.. I am not sure what these exit status mean.

Can some one please pass the list of TWS exit status with their Description.

Answer (score 1):

TWS does not come with its own exit status for jobs, the return codes you have in the logs come from the systems the jobs run on.

TWS is just a wrapper to the script/binaries you run : it submits the script/program you want to run to the system (with the user defined in job def.) and gives you back the RC and the logs if any.

About return codes, in TWS you have the option when you define a job to modify job RC using return code mapping. For example, you can specify a successful status of a job if RC is 0 or RC < 1 or RC = 128 and everything in between. Look for RCCONDSUCC in documentation.